# What I learned/have learned from quitting my job is

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I have another situation/context with the verb "learn":

If I quit my job 3 months ago, now I meet my friends and say:

> What I **learned/have learned** from quitting my job is that doing what
> you like is the happiest thing in your life.

I think that both are good to use. Right?

I would like to hear from both BrE and AmE.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would use **have learned** because the learning has been going on during those three months. American usage may be different.

Comment: As an American English speaker, either one sounds natural to me.  **have learned** puts the emphasis on my situation now; **learned** puts the emphasis on what happened then.